# Vscode can't find the compiler, but I've already install it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to vscode,just gonna try it out until I bump into this problem
[Can't find compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d78lw.png)

According to the pic, it said I didn't have any compiler, while I've already install c++ extension, which shouldn't be the case.
[c++ extension installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMl1F.png)

Comment: You ned to install a c++ compiler, have you tried the instructions on the vscode page? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: `The C/C++ extension does not include a C++ compiler or debugger. You will need to install these tools or use those already installed on your computer.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also install a c++ compiler for vscode to compiler your code, along with the c++ compiler.

Mingw-x64 is one framework which will allow you to compile c/c++ code

[CPP instructions on VSCode site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

[MinGW instructions on VSCode site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: now I encounter a problem while installing Mingw-w64, when I run "pacman -Syu" , which is required to finish installing according to msys2.org , it showed "bash: $'\302\226\302\226pacman': command not found "

Comment: are you on linux or windows?

Comment: i'm currently on window

Comment: can you try restarting your command window or run it outside vscode from cmd? [check these steps also once](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2218)

Comment: Neither of these work

Comment: ok I can think of why, install [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe) and then [reinstall mysys2](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: well this time another error occur when running the same command "error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
mintty: /usr/share/mintty/themes/helmholtz exists in filesystem
mintty: /usr/share/mintty/themes/kohlrausch exists in filesystem
mintty: /usr/share/mintty/themes/luminous exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded."

Comment: i assume that i uninstall the previous one the wrong way, i uninstall it  by using the Add/Remove Program feature in the Window's Control Panel.

Comment: oh I fixed it by manually deleting the files and install it again.

Comment: i can find the compiler now! Thanks for your help! Though when I compile it there's another problem, I'll make another question thread since it's a different problem.

Comment: great I thought you gave up. ;) good luck in your coding adventures